# Use std::experimental::optional to implement a list

Tags: c++, list, data-structures, c++14

I was wondering if it is possible to implement a single (and possible double) linked list using `std::experimental::optional`.

```
template <typename T>
struct node {
    std::experimental::optional<node<T>> next;
    T data;
};
```

What are the advantages/disadvantages of such a design? Could new `c++1z` features be used to implement sentinels, or getting rid of them alltogether? Would this scale up to *n-ary* trees as well?

Comment: Did you try it? Looks like the first node is going to contain all others as values instead of pointers? Not sure how well that is going to scale.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is not possible to implement a linked list in that way, because your `node`-type will always be incomplete. Here is a [more complete example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d96889c0ede0997) that illustrates the issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/optional>

template <typename T>
struct node {
    std::experimental::optional<node<T>> next;
    T data;
};

int main( int, char ** )
{
    std::cout << sizeof( node<int> ) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The point is that `optional<T>` requires `T` to be complete but at the point where you define `next`, `node` is incomplete. The reason why `optional<T>` needs a complete type is that it stores `T` directly within the `optional` object, i.e. it does not allocate memory on the heap. As a result, it has to know the size of `T`. Internally, it contains a buffer of `sizeof( T )`. In terms of memory layout, you can think of `optional<T>` as

```
template <class T>
struct optional
{
    bool _containsValue;
    char _buffer[ sizeof( T ) ];
};
```

but in practice, it is more complicated, due to memory alignment requirements.

In your case, in order to know the size of `optional<node>`, it has to know the size of `node` and for this it has to know the size of `optional<node>`.

Answer (score 10):

It's impossible because the `optional<T>` requires `T` to be complete.

As per [N3672](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3672.html) (the proposal for `std::optional`):

> Class template optional imposes little requirements on T: it has to be either an lvalue reference type, or a complete object type satisfying the requirements of Destructible.

Comment: That is, `sizeof(node)` must be at least `sizeof(next) + sizeof(data)` and `sizeof(next)` must be greater than `sizeof(node)`...

Comment: Does the same requirement hold for ``std::experimental::variant``?

Comment: @j.dog Not sure about the `std::experimental::variant`, but `boost::variant` does require complete types (when not using `boost::recursive_variant`, which uses dynamic allocation to store it outside of the object).

Comment: Mentioning the fundamental reason, that an `optional<T>` contains enough data inside itself to store a `T`, would be better than *only* citing the standard.

Comment: @Yakk Yeah, as with all such answers, one hopes the Standard imposes such requirements for a reason, and ultimately it's that reason that's interesting.